# Calculating number of changes using Analytic Functions

Tags: oracle, function, lag

I want to calculate number of changes at E-Mail address per year:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT  1 as customer_id,'a@gmail.com' as email,2010 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
            SELECT 1 as customer_id,'a@yahoo.com' as email,2011 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 2 as customer_id,'b@yahoo.com' as email,2010 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 3 as customer_id,'c@yahoo.com' as email,2012 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 3 as customer_id,'c@google.com' as email,2012 as year FROM DUAL
          ) 
        SELECT year, customer_id,email,
               LAG(email,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY email) as email_prev,
               sum(case when email <> LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sal) then 1 else 0 end ) changes
          FROM t
;
```

ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here.

Results should be:

```
Year  changes
====  =======
2010  1
2012  1
2018  20
```

Comment: Where do you get your years and numbers of changes from? Your sample data has 2010, 2011 and 2012 but your results have 2010, 2012 and 2018 and there are only 5 rows in the input but you have 22 changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not what you really trying, is it? there's no SAL column in the t CTE, so the query won't run, even if you take care of the error. Try this query:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT  1 as customer_id,'a@gmail.com' as email,2010 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
            SELECT 1 as customer_id,'a@yahoo.com' as email,2011 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 2 as customer_id,'b@yahoo.com' as email,2010 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 3 as customer_id,'c@yahoo.com' as email,2012 as year FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 3 as customer_id,'c@google.com' as email,2012 as year FROM DUAL
          ), 
t1 as (        SELECT year, customer_id,email,
               LAG(email,1) OVER(partition by customer_id ORDER BY email) as email_prev
       from t)
  select year,customer_id,
               sum(case when email <> email_prev or email_prev is null then 1 else 0 end ) changes
          FROM t1
group by year,customer_id;
```

This is the output:

```
YEAR    CUSTOMER_ID CHANGES
2010    2               1
2010    1               1
2011    1               1
2012    3               2
```

Comment: That is right. But the query should in fact show changes against previous year and grouped by year not customer_id

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH t ( customer_id, email, year ) AS (
  SELECT 1,'a@gmail.com',  2010 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,'a@yahoo.com',  2011 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'b@yahoo.com',  2010 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,'c@yahoo.com',  2012 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,'c@google.com', 2012 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT year,
       COUNT(1) AS total_changes,
       COUNT( DISTINCT customer_id ) AS num_customers_changed_email
FROM   (
  SELECT year,
         customer_id,
         email,
         CASE email
         WHEN LAG( email, 1 ) OVER( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY year )
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END as has_changed_email
  FROM   t
)
WHERE has_changed_email = 1
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> YEAR | TOTAL_CHANGES | NUM_CUSTOMERS_CHANGED_EMAIL
> ---: | ------------: | --------------------------:
> 2010 |             2 |                           2
> 2011 |             1 |                           1
> 2012 |             2 |                           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d5f60993ca19f66c3a69772080dc034)*